# ¿Se puede agregar dos funciones a un solo botón en un formulario Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

Necesito saber como asignarle como ya dije 2 funciones a un botón, en este caso el botón "buscar", la idea es llenar el *Jtextfield* con el número de ficha de un registro y buscarlo (esa sería una función), la otra es que al no digitar ningún número en el *textfield* y darle buscar se listen todos los registros en la BD correspondiente.

```
public DefaultTableModel buscar()
{
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM PERSONA WHERE num_ficha='"+num_ficha+"'";
    Conectar conectar = new Conectar();
    return conectar.listar(sql);
}
```

ese metodo se lo asigno al boton y consigo buscar segun numero de ficha

```
private void btnBuscarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    persona.setNum_ficha(Integer.parseInt(frmPersona.txtNumFicha.getText()));
    frmPersona.tabla.setModel(new DefaultTableModel());
    frmPersona.tabla.setModel(persona.buscar());
}
```

Acá ya está asignado pero me falta la otra función de listar. ¿Cómo la puedo agregar al botón?

Comment: Que tal si añades un condicional dentro de la acción de una sola función, si cumple la condición de campo vacío ejecute el código de búsqueda general, caso contrario que busque un dato específico, no necesitas asignarle dos funciones al mismo botón.

Comment: no estoy seguro de entender lo que dices, como seria eso? me darias un ejemplo porfavor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente solo necesitas una función asociada al botón, lo que harías dentro de la función es consultar si el campo JTextfield está vacío optar por buscar todos los registros de la base, caso contrario buscar el registro que coincida con el JTextfield, algo así:

```
private void btnBuscarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    //si el campo está vacío consulta toda la tabla
    if(frmPersona.txtNumFicha.getText().compareTo("") == 0){
        //Aquí puedes llamar a una función diferente que busque tal como tu función buscar 
        //pero sin la sentencia WHERE.
    }else{//caso contrario busca un dato específico                                     
        persona.setNum_ficha(Integer.parseInt(frmPersona.txtNumFicha.getText()));
        frmPersona.tabla.setModel(new DefaultTableModel());
        frmPersona.tabla.setModel(persona.buscar());
    }
}
```